# How to revert to/download the VS2022 Preview 2 version

Tags: visual-studio, code-templates, visual-studio-2022

The problem I'm facing in the new Preview 3 version is the new templates. I myself don't like the top-level statements and/or hiding namespaces and classes and I would very much appreciate a way to bring back the old templates. After reading through the comments on their blog, it seems there are is no effort to add an option to get the old templates back.

So, I would like to know how I can download/downgrade my version of Visual Studio 2022 to the older Preview 2 to get back the old templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, you can create .NET Core 5 application of the type you need in VS 2022 and after you create it, change the target framework from project properties to .NET 6.

I have tested with web application and .NET Core 5 and 3.1 are still created using the "old" templates.

I am using the currently latest 2022 Preview 3.1.

Comment: I mostly have come to terms with new templates, still hate em tho. I guess this solved the question. Good day sir!